# How to find a special integrating factor which is not in form of $x^m y^n$ but is both function of $x$ and $y$?

Tags: line-integrals

I was watching [this](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=efBdnK1q504&t=0s&index=8&list=PLj7p5OoL6vGykv4JM5MpY3I5j6mkLyKQU) youtube video.

Now I would wonder what if special integrating factor had been a function of $x$ and $y$ other than some exponential function of $x$ and $y$. Then how should we get that?

suppose you have this differential equation $$(2xy^2 \sec y + 2x\frac{\tan y}{y}) dx + (3x^2y \sec y +3y \sec y +\frac{x^2}{y}) dy = 0$$ how would you get the integrating factor of the above differential equation?

although it is $y\cos y$

Comment: I tried to make what you wrote more readable, though you might want to check.  In particular, your *differential equation* does not look like an equation

Comment: @Henry what's wrong in it ? Please tell me.  I'll try to improve.

Comment: @Henry anyway thanks for editing

Comment: equations often have an equals sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(2xy^2 \sec y + 2x\frac{\tan y}{y}) dx + (3x^2y \sec y +3y \sec y +\frac{x^2}{y}) dy = 0$$
The integrating factor is $y\cos(y)$ . After reducing to the common denominator, this is easy to guess. If you cannot see it at first place, try various forms of integrating factors. When trying an integrating factor of the form $f(y)$ you find the function $f(y)$ by identification.

Checking :

$$y\cos(y)(2xy^2 \sec y + 2x\frac{\tan y}{y}) dx + y\cos(y)(3x^2y \sec y +3y \sec y +\frac{x^2}{y}) dy = 0$$

$$(2xy^3 + 2x\sin(y)) dx + (3x^2y^2 +3y^2 +x^2\sin(y)) dy = 0$$
$$d\left(x^2y^3+y^3+x^2\sin(y)\right)=0$$
$$x^2y^3+y^3+x^2\sin(y)=c$$